# ILDASM and ILASM, how use them?

Tags: c#, disassembly, cil, ildasm, ilasm

I'm having a hard time trying to (Dis)assemble a dll using the Visual Studio command prompt, don't look that simple as I see [in the microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler).

I'm using the ildasm for these way:

```
ildasm myLibrary.dll output:MyLibrary.il
```

And I get: **Unable to open 'MyLibrary.il' for output.**

I also tried the full path:

```
ildasm directory\myLibrary.dll output:directory\MyLibrary.il
```

And I get: **MULTIPLE INPUT FILES SPECIFIED**

Using the ildasm GUI actually works, but when I use the ilasm:

```
ilasm myLibrary.il /dll
```

I get: **Could not open 'myLibrary.il'**, when I use the full path I get the same error.

What's wrong here?

Comment: For `ildasm` it appears you left out the `/` that is used to introduce options. Try `ildasm myLibrary.dll /output:MyLibrary.il`

Comment: In VS2019, nothing worked for file arguments until they were quoted with **""**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simple, let's take this line of code:

```
using System;      
public class sample  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside main ...");
    }
}
```

Let us compile `App.cs` to `App.exe`. This executable now prints Inside main … when we run it.

**Now let us attempt to change the output of this executable without touching its source files.**

You run `ildasm App.exe /out:App.il` **to generate the IL code corresponding to the executable**. You can now edit this il code in notepad and change the `ldstr` from “Inside main …” to “Inside main changed …” as shown below:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Inside main ..."
IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ret
```

To

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Inside main changed ..."
IL_0006:  call       void  [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ret
```

Now let us rebuild the executable from this il file by running `ilasm App.il.` This generates a new App.exe. If you run App.exe you will get the following output “Inside main changed …”

There are useful posts in [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae06dad3-ed61-46ed-ba99-363d53ffb65d/using-ildasm-ilasm-to-updated-resources?forum=clr) and in [c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c4d11a/understanding-how-to-write-a-basic-C-Sharp-program-using-ildasm/) as well guiding through the use of ILDASM and ILASM.

Comment: It's kinda frustracting, I try a new project and I get: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools>ildasm ConsoleApp1.exe /out:ConsoleApp.il
Unable to open 'ConsoleApp.il' for output.`

Comment: because your .il is probably read only or your don't have enough permissions, try removing the read only or working with administrator privilages

Comment: Open the CMD with elevated privileges

Comment: @FreddxL. change to a folder where you have write permissions

Answer (score 0):

`ildasm myLibrary.dll -output=MyLibrary.il`

DO NOT USE OPTION KEY "/" ON LINUX OR OSX.

'/' is system path separator.